# How do I remove the rows of duplicates based on a "key" column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am elaborating an Excel file with a lot of rows, and many of these are duplicates.

I created a "key" column which contains data from 3 of the adjacent columns, and contain the relevant data, and used conditional formatting in order to highlight the duplicates and filter them.

The key column is formatted as: `=B1428&" , "&C1428&" , "&J1428`

This concatenates the cells referenced above, and separates them with a comma.

If i perform the "Remove Duplicates" operation, Excel returns in the same column all the unique data, but it doesn't remove the relative row.

How do I remove the duplicates so that also the relative row is deleted and not just the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find last row of column A

         For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1 '<- Loop from row last row to 1

            If Application.CountIf(.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow), .Range("A" & i).Value) > 1 Then '<- If a value appears more that 1 time
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!